# Text-box size not increasing after certain limit

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using `textbox` field in my `.cshtml` file and I want to increase the size of `textbox` after increasing `width` and `size` factors the size is increasing but up to a certain limit

```
    <label name="To">
        TO : <br />
        <input id="TO" type="text" size="50" name="To" /><br />
        @*<textarea cols="800" rows="1" style="overflow:visible"></textarea>*@
    </label> <br />

    <label name="CC">
        CC : <br />
        <input type="text" size="300" name="CC" /><br />
    </label><br />

    <label name="Subject">
        Subject : <br />
        <input type="text" size="300" width="300" name="Subject" /><br />
    </label>
```

Comment: your `textbox` is in `label` tag so it is constrained by the size of the `label` and if the `label` is in a `container` it will be constrained by the size of the `container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

your `textbox` is in `label` tag so it is constrained by the size of the `label` and if the `label` is in a `container` it will be constrained by the size of the `container`

Please take your `textboxes` out of the `label`, I don't think you want to do that. So like the below

```
<label name="CC">
      CC : 
 </label><br />
 <input type="text" size="300" name="CC" />
<br />


 <label name="Subject">
     Subject : 
  </label><br />
 <input type="text" size="300" width="300" name="Subject" />
<br />
```

Hope this helps